# what is the most efficient way to debug `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my application I get `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`. This is caused by using `event.preventDefault()` inside `$stateChangeStart` event handler:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

When I do that, `ui-router` constantly tries to change state and `$stateChangeStart` is fired multiple times. This could be the problem. I think I'd need to debug digest to understand what constantly returns the same value. I'm wondering how would you do that? I'm thinking about detaching all modules to  have as little watchers as possible.